# How to store same id when editing a post while being admin and not the user the post belongs

Tags: php, laravel

I have a forum on my Website and when i access it via admin rights and edit a post i did not make,it changes the stored data from the userid to my admin id hence changing the post as if i made it ,instead of the other person.I dont know how to change it

Since this is my first Website im not sure how to change the code.
I figured i might want a if statement but i already have a construct.

```
AdminController: 
        public function storepost(){
        {
        $user = Auth::user();

        // logged in?
        if(!$user) {
            request()->session()->flash('error', 'No permission!');
            return redirect('/');
        }

        // New post or edit old one
        if (request('id')) {
            $post = Post::find(request('id'));
        } else {
            $post = new Post();
        }

        $dummypost = new Post();
        $rules = $dummypost->rules();

        // every form filled in ?
        $validatedData = request()->validate($rules);

        // save post
        $post->title = $validatedData['title'];
        $post->description = $validatedData['description'];
        $post->user_id = $user->id;
        $post->save();

        //back to forum
        return redirect('admin/forum');
    }
```

i want to edit posts it changes them to id 1 which is admin. but it had a id of 2 in the database.i want them to stay 2 even after i edited them

Comment: Why are you updating the `id` at first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that when i edited the post, it changed the user to me (i was the admin) instead of just editing the parts out that i wanted.I fixed that with the if statement:

```
if (!$user->admin){
            $post->user_id = $user->id;
        }
```

I had a boolean value in my database which u can see with admin.so the if statement simply says if user is not admin,

post user_id as user_id.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `if check` will be okay, notice how on the line above `saving your post model` you are assigning the `user_id` to the currently logged in user, we need to restrict that to assign the id only when the user is not `Admin`, so change that line to this:

```
if (/* Check if $user is not admin */) {
    $post->user_id = $user->id;
    //or if you have relationship and it's one to one
    $post->user()->associate($user);
}
$post->save();
```

Or if you don't want to update `user_id` of your post each time you edit that post as `Non admin user` you can completely omit that line by removing/commenting it out.

```
...
// $post->user_id = $user->id;
// Or completely remove it
...
```

Comment: Your solution is okay BUT why would one want to update the `id` again and again?

Comment: Just noticed his last sentence in the post after looking at your comment, you are right, I will change the answer then, thanks

Comment: i just used if (!$user->admin){$post->user_id =$user->id; thank you for your help. im still new to this and i was pretty sure it would be a simple solution.

Comment: You are welcome, also check my updated answer, in case you don't need to update the `user_id` after the `post` has been created

Answer (score 0):

As you said your id 1 is an admin then you can put a condition like as below.

```
if($user->id != '1'){
  $post->user_id = $user->id;
}
```

It will update user_id only when it's not an admin. If you have boolean "parameter" then code might look like this

```
if($user->YOURPARAMETER == 1){  //I Assume parameter would be is_admin
  $post->user_id = $user->id;
}
```

Comment: but does that not mean that once another admin with a different id comes he cant edit the posts? posts have user_id , and i have a different table for users with a boolean for admins. so basically i could use the table users->admin that would work right?

Comment: ohh if you have boolean then condition should be on that parameter instead on "id". That will work perfectly for your case.